# Grouping text by characters into dictionary of chacartes with Unicode code points in Hex format

Tags: c#

I'm trying to group a text by characters into dictionary and returning the Unicode code point of each character. I'm using the following code

```
private Dictionary< Char, int> GetChars(string input)
    {

        return input.GroupBy(ch => ch)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => (int) g.Key);
    }
```

This code returns the Unicode code points of the characters in decimal format, but i want it in Hex format. Any help please ?

Edit:

Example: Input A 
         Output 65

Shouldn't be 41 ?

the right solution

```
 private Dictionary< Char, string> GetChars(string input)
    {

        return input.GroupBy(ch => ch)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => ((int) g.Key).ToString("x"));
    }
```

Comment: what is your input, and sample output. You should be getting integers.

Comment: Guessing that you clicked on the "Hex" button in Visual studio, that shows you output in hex. It's just integers.

Comment: @RoadBump, so how to change it again to Hexadecimal?

Comment: Dont know if its a very nice solution. But you can use .ToString("X") to convert an int to hex...

Comment: @  Evelie, I just did that before your comment, and it is the right solution :)

Comment: @Falah posting a solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Int i = 64;
string hex = i.ToString("X");
```

Comment: Yes, if you only input one character. But in this case, what's the reason for grouping?

Comment: @Alex, I'm grouping ling text. Have a look at my edit in the original post please.

Comment: Yes, but you end up with a `Dictionary<char, string>`, not `Dictionary<char, int>`.

Comment: Sorry Alex, it was my mistake

Comment: I was under the impression it was okey with having string since you cant display a hex value with an int. But Ill throw you an upvote aswel Alex!

Answer (score 2):

`A` has 65 as decimal code, `a` has 97 as decimal code. Also, the `A` character has 41 as hexadecimal code and `101` as octal code. Take a look [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

You might want to add a second parameter to your method and call it according to your context:

```
class Program
{
    enum LetterConversion
    {
        ToLower,
        ToUpper,
        None
    }

    private static Dictionary<Char, int> 
        GetChars(string input, LetterConversion conversion)
    {
        switch (conversion)
        {
            case LetterConversion.ToLower:
                input = input.ToLower();
                break;
            case LetterConversion.ToUpper:
                input = input.ToUpper();
                break;
        }
        return input.GroupBy(ch => ch)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => 
            int.Parse(String.Format("{0:X}", (int)g.Key)));

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // the values will be 97, 98, 99
        var d1 = GetChars("abcA", LetterConversion.ToLower);

        // the values will be 65, 66, 67
        var d2 = GetChars("abcA", LetterConversion.ToUpper);

        // the values will be 97, 98, 99, 65
        var d3 = GetChars("abcA", LetterConversion.None);
    }
}
```